# Storing records of a table in sorted files in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Does MYSQL automatically stores the records of a table in sorted files (in hard disks) while using a primary key or auto-increment in a field? If that is the case then what about the records of a particular table that are inserted at different points of time? Confused!

Comment: The pointers to the records are stored multiple times, for each key. Hence inserting a record forces the key files to be shuffled around to put the new value in an appropriate place. So while having indexes massively helps searches of tables they do slow down inserts.

Comment: actually i want to know that whether or not mysql or any other dbms stores records in sorted files if i use primary key or not? @Kickstart

Comment: Afraid I don't know. My feeling is that MySQL would store the records in insert order with a store of the primary key in order with pointers to the main records. Might be worth checking SQLite